# Do Many-To-Many relationships required a "join entity" in Symfony 2 / Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am starting to understand how Symfony 2 and Doctrine handle many to many relationships, but I am stuck on something, that I seem to have read differing opinions on.

Let's say I have an Author entity and a Book entity...with a many-to-many relationship between them.

In my database, I represent this with three tables, an `authors` table, a `books` table, and an `authors_books` table (which basically just joins them together.

In Symfony 2, do I also create an `AuthorsBooks` entity, which would have the sole purpose of joining the Author and Book entities together? Or, does Symfony handle that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is nothing else than the association of authors and books, you don't need to create the `AuthorsBooks` entity.

You have two options now, Unidirectional or Bidirectional. You'll be able to find more information directly in Doctrine2 documentation [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional)

For unidirectional, you'll have something like that (yml):

```
Author:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    bookList:
      targetEntity: Group
      joinTable:
        name: authors_books
          joinColumns:
            user_id:
              referencedColumnName: id
          inverseJoinColumns:
            book_id:
              referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: I chose this answer cuz it supplied some more options, but both were great!

Answer (score 1):

Symfony has nothing to do with this, it's strictly Doctrine's thing. But, no, you do not have to create a `AuthorsBooks` entity. All you have to do is to configure Doctrine properly, i.e. use [`@JoinTable` annotation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional) that specifies which table should be used to join two entities.